# Viewpager in FragmentActivity themed as Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My app has a Gridview. Clicking on the Gridview cell used to open an activity which was themed as a dialog in the manifest. This worked well.

To improvise the app further, I wanted to add a viewpager in the activity. So I changed `SomeClass extends Activity` to `SomeClass extends Fragment`. I created a container (which `extends FragmentActivity`) to hold this `Fragment` and I themed this container as a Dialog in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.packagename.SomeContainer"  android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dialog" />
```

This doesn't show the Fragment as a dialog. It shows the fragment full screen which I don't want and it doesn't resize based on the content, which it did when it was an Activity.

How should I display the container (fragmentactivity) or the fragment as a dialog which should resize according to the content and not display full-screen?

SomeContainer.java

```
public class SomeContainer extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private SomeAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_from_left, R.anim.hold);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_events);

        getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String date_string = intent.getStringExtra("date_string");


        mAdapter = new SomeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), date_string);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.eventspager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.pull_out_to_left);
        super.onPause();
    }


    public static class SomeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String date;
        FragmentManager fm;
        public SomeAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String date) {
            super(fm);
            this.date = date;
            this.fm = fm;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return SomeFragment.newInstance(date);
            case 1:
                return SomeFragment1.newInstance(date);
            case 2:
                return SomeFragment2.newInstance(date);

            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SomeFragment.java

```
public class SomeFragment extends DialogFragment  {

    String date_string;

    public static SomeFragment newInstance(String date) {
        SomeFragment someFragment = new SomeFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("date", date);
        someFragment.setArguments(args);

        returnsomeFragment;
    }

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);

        //getActivity().getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        date_string = getArguments().getString("date");

        //do something

        return v;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should extend DialogFragment

Comment: @Milanix, I did. Doesn't make any difference.